# Toggle class should not clicked again

Tags: jquery

If a button has active class then it should not toggle if I click on it again.
Here I have two buttons **"Grid View"** and **"List View"** I want when **"Grid View"** is active and still I click on it this should not toggle active class.

```js
$('.switch-btn').click(function(e){
  $('.switch-btn.grid, .switch-btn.list').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
button.switch-btn {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button.switch-btn.active {
    background: green;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="switch-btn grid active">Grid View</button>
<button class="switch-btn list">List View</button>
```

Comment: Actually from you question, `I want when "Grid View" is active..`, you can translate your words into `if ($('.switch-btn.grid).hasClass('active')){ // then what } else { // then what }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add checker for the class existence, like below:

```js
$('.switch-btn').click(function(e){
  const cButton = $(e.currentTarget);
  
  if (cButton.hasClass('active'))
    return;
    
  $('.switch-btn.grid, .switch-btn.list').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
button.switch-btn {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button.switch-btn.active {
  background: green;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<button class="switch-btn grid active">Grid View</button>
<button class="switch-btn list">List View</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
$('.switch-btn.grid, .switch-btn.list').toggleClass('active');
```

to this:

```
$(".switch-btn").removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

In your case you always toggle the class, even if an element already has class `active`. But let's say that none of those buttons has class `active`. Then your function will add class `active` to both elements.

(Your version with none elements with class `active`)

```js
$('.switch-btn').click(function(e){
  $('.switch-btn.grid, .switch-btn.list').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
button.switch-btn {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button.switch-btn.active {
    background: green;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="switch-btn grid">Grid View</button>
<button class="switch-btn list">List View</button>
```

In my solution you firstly remove `active` class from all elements with class `switch-btn` and then add to the clicked one.

```js
$('.switch-btn').click(function(e){
  $(".switch-btn").removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
button.switch-btn {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button.switch-btn.active {
    background: green;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="switch-btn grid">Grid View</button>
<button class="switch-btn list">List View</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if `$(this)` has  the class `'active'`

```js
$('.switch-btn').click(function(e){
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $('.switch-btn.grid, .switch-btn.list').toggleClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
button.switch-btn {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button.switch-btn.active {
    background: green;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="switch-btn grid active">Grid View</button>
<button class="switch-btn list">List View</button>
```